# Not able to validate the Select option in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to validate the Select option in Angular 6, Aria-required or required doesn't seem to help.

it should display a message or show RED border as shown in html forms.

Html part of the code

Category 
                

                  Select Category
                  {{category.name}}

```
        <div class="column">
          <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status </label><br />
          <!-- <select class='select-option dropdown-align' [(ngModel)]='statusSelected' (ngModelChange)='onStatusSelected($event)'> -->
            <select class='select-option dropdown-align' [(ngModel)]='statusSelected' (ngModelChange)='onStatusSelected($event)'>

            <option [ngValue]="select">Select status</option>
            <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>


onCategorysSelected(event) {
    console.log(event)
    event = parseInt(event)
    this.categorysSelected = event;//option value will be sent as event

  }
```

Comment: the code is of a project so can't post whole project code sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="column">
              <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status<span class="requiredMark">*</span></label><br />
              <select class='select-option dropdown-align' [(ngModel)]='statusSelected' (ngModelChange)='onStatusSelected($event)'>
                <!-- <select  class='select-option dropdown-align' [(ngModel)]='statusSelected'> -->

                <option [ngValue]="select">Select status</option>
                <option  class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
              </select>
              <small class="text-danger" [hidden]=statusvalid>
              <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Change status
              </small>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your **statusSelected** as null, then put *required* tag to selectbox. Try this,

```
   <select required class='select-option dropdown-align' [(ngModel)]='statusSelected' (ngModelChange)='onStatusSelected($event)'>    
    <option [ngValue]="">Select status</option>
    <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
```

Note that If you put [ngValue]="select", 'select' string will be your value and required tag will not work correctly.

Comment: I'm using this structure since angular2, can you please produce StackBlitz for us?